# How to make gradle processResources task faster

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build, build.gradle

I'm working on Spring Boot project and I'm suffering from build time.  My Project's processResources task takes too long.

If resources file is up-to-date, It just takes about 10 seconds.
But if file changes at least one, It takes over minutes.
It's because one resource library takes over 90000+ files.

I tried to use --build-cache option, but it seems like not working in processResources task.

Can I make processResources task works on only changed files? How can I make processResources task faster?

Comment: "because one resource library takes over 90000+ files" why do you have that many files? Which resource library is it?

Comment: Is a file changing in that resource library? If it's not, then I'd split it out: create a separate task to process just the resources of that library, have processResources depend on it, and let Gradle track that is almost always up-to-date. That way, other resource file changes won't affect Gradle's up-to-date checking for the slow library.

Comment: @g00glen00b I'm using [material-design-icons](https://github.com/Templarian/MaterialDesign) library

Comment: @nickb Can you please elaborate to achieve that? I'm new to gradle.

Comment: @shj Do you really need the individual `.*design` or `*.svg` files? If you use `npm install @mdi/font` it should only install the CSS and the webfont, which would decrease the amount of files significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Use exclusions!

```
processResources {
    exclude '**/*.svg'     // Exclude all SVG files
    exclude '**/design/**' // Exclude whole "design" directory
}
```